# ¿existe alguna librería de expresiones regulares que permita hacer un 'lookbehind' de tamaño variable?

Tags: regex

Estoy diseñando una serie de expresiones regulares para procesamiento de lenguage natural en español. Sin embargo me he enfrentado con el dilema del "mirar atrás" `lookbehind` en los distintos *sabores* `flavours` de RegEx. No he podido dar con ninguno que permita hacer un `lookbehind` (positivo o negativo) con una expresión de longitud variable.

1. ¿Existe alguna librería que lo permita en cualquier plataforma?

**[Ejemplo PCRE](https://regexr.com/3pnfh)**

2. ¿Es esto imposible? ¿Por qué?

Comment: **¿En qué lenguaje?**  ...1. Sí. En .Net ... 2. No entendí la pregunta. Si estás preguntando el porqué, es por cómo está diseñado el motor de regex de cada  dialecto (*flavor*), ya que internamente retroceden n posiciones e intentan un *lookahead*... 3. ¿Por qué no nos explicás el problema? La mayoría de los casos (si no todos) se pueden resolver **sin** un *lookbehind*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí se puede, pero veamos en detalle:

La mayoría de los *sabores* **regex** no permiten usar cualquier expresión regular dentro de un `lookbehind` porque no pueden aplicar una expresión regular al revés. El motor regex debe poder determinar cuántos caracteres retroceder antes de verificar la expresión `lookbehind`. Al evaluarla, el motor determina la longitud de la expresión regular y retrocede esa cantidad de caracteres en la cadena y luego aplica la expresión regular de izquierda a derecha tal como lo haría con una expresión regular normal. Por eso la mayoría de los motores regex sólo pueden realizar `lookbehind` con sub-expresiones de longitud fija (`fixed-length`). **JavaScript** y **Tcl** no permiten `lookbehind` aunque si `lookahead`.

Muchos motores, incluidos los utilizados por **Perl**, **Python** y **Boost** solo permiten cadenas de longitud fija. Puedes usar texto literal, caracteres escapados, Unicode (excepto `\X`) y clases de caracteres (`[...]`). No puedes usar cuantificadores o referencias para atrás (`backreferences`). Puedes usar barras (`pipes`) para opciones alternativas, pero ¡solo si todas las alternativas tienen la misma longitud!. Estos *sabores* evalúan la expresión retrocediendo primero a través de la cadena tantos caracteres como necesita la sub-expresión  `lookbehind` y luego la aplican de la izquierda a la derecha de forma normal.

**PCRE** (que es el ejemplo que usaste) no igual a **Perl** en este aspecto ya que **PCRE** permite alternativas de longitud diferentes, pero todas debe ser longitud fija. Otros motores con comportamiento similar a este son los de: **PHP**, **Delphi**, **R** y **Ruby**.

**Java** (6+) lo lleva un pasito más adelante pudiendo usar sub-expresiones de longitud variable pero finita, es decir, permite usar `?` y `{1,3}`  pero no `*` ó `+`. **Java** determina el mínimo y máximos posibles de la subexpresión y prueba todas las posibilidades.

Por último, la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Los únicos motores de expresiones regulares que permiten usar una expresión regular completa dentro de `lookbehind`, incluyendo `*` y `+` y las referencias para atrás (revisar si un grupo capturado existe antes de su captura), son el motor **JGsoft** y las clases RegEx de **.NET framework**.

Lo que hacen estos motores es aplicar la expresión regular `lookbehind` **de derecha a izquierda**, sólo necesitan evaluar la sub expresión una vez, independientemente de la cantidad de diferentes longitudes posibles que tenga.

Comment: ¡Ea! Muchas gracias. Ahora entiendo. Voy a revisar `JGsoft` porque no me gusta `.NET`